# Error with query in SugarORM

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm trying to get number of rows in my Sugar database for each month. My DATE_INSERT is String value like dd-MM-yyyy. I'm trying to set query, but getting error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIKE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM EXERCISE_DATA WHERE DATE_INSERT LIKE
```

Here's my method. I'm trying to get list size for each month and draw it via GraphView:

```
private DataPoint[] generateYearlyData() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.JANUARY);
        int monthIndex = 12;
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[monthIndex];
        for (int i=0; i < monthIndex; i++) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy");
            String queryMonth = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            String completeArgs = new StringBuilder().append("'%").
                    append(queryMonth).append("%'").toString();
            double x = i;
            double y = (double) ExerciseData.findWithQuery(ExerciseData.class,
                    "SELECT * FROM EXERCISE_DATA WHERE DATE_INSERT LIKE",completeArgs).size();
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
            values[i] = v;
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
        return values;
    }
```

Comment: Do you possibly need a space after `LIKE`?

Comment: Yeah, Tim. I've just found. I can solve problem only after post in Stackoverflow=)

Comment: Check the answer given by @CL. below as it is probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `findWithQuery` is a parameter value, or a list of parameter values. These values are inserted into the query string at the places that are marked with a [parameter marker](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).

Your query does not contain any parameter markers. You need to write `... LIKE ?`.